Password validation doesn't respect altered policy
I use Firebase Authentication to manage my users and I have set the password policy to require a minimum password length of 8.

But when I open the email link to reset my password, when I use a weak password (for example: enter 8 spaces), the error message does not meet the minimum password requirements I set.

import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, sendPasswordResetEmail } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: //
};
  
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = getAuth();

sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Password reset email sent');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });

Is there any way I can adjust this error message without customizing the password reset page?
